# Regular Expression to validate ApplicationUser email address in ASP.net MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I am creating a webapp in asp.net MVC5 which will only allow people with a certain domain to sign up.

From what I understand the easiest way is to use a regular expression. Is there any way to use Data Annotations to change the model, or do I have to play around with the view to achieve this?

Comment: Use the `[RegularExpression]` attribute on your property.

Comment: Where is the email property stored? I cannot find it anywhere in the models

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably a bit too late now but I would suggest as follows:

I've have an app in which I need to modify some of ApplicationUser properties, I am trying something which haven't tested on real life yet, but my Unit Tests are passing so far, it could be useful for you.

Override Email property in ApplicationUser, and add a custom validation annotation:

```
[ValidateEmailDomain(ErrorMessage = "Not a valid email domain.")]    
public override string Email { get; set; }
```

ValidateEmailDomain code:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Web;

namespace WATHEVER
{
    public class ValidateEmailDomain: RequiredAttribute
    {
        public override bool IsValid(object value)
        {
            //code
        }
    }
}
```

Note that as ValidateEmailDomain inherits from RequiredAttribute it will become obviously obligatory, if you don't want it that way, you could validate it also when it's null.

Sorry for my English :/

Answer (score 0):

with MVC 5 you're using ASPNET Identiy, and the basic properties are encapsulate inside IdentityUser, so for your case, you cannot have access direct to the field email, but yuo can use EF Fluent API to add some rules, **the but part is that regularexpression attribute is not part of the EF Fluent API**.

If you need to see how can you use EF Fluent API with ASPNET Identity:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    { }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        //Define rules
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>()
        .Property(u => u.Email).IsRequired();
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}
```

Regards,